# GPflow simple Coregionalisation Model with heteroscedastic noise - learnt noise parameters not shown

Tags: tensorflow, gaussian-process, gpflow

I have implemented the following GP model:

```
likelihood = gpflow.likelihoods.HeteroskedasticTFPConditional(
    distribution_class=tfp.distributions.Normal,  # Gaussian Likelihood
    scale_transform=tfp.bijectors.Exp(), # Exponential Transform
)
lik = gpflow.likelihoods.SwitchedLikelihood([likelihood_orig, likelihood_orig])

coreg.W = np.random.rand(output_dim, rank)  # Initialise the W matrix
kern = k1 * coreg
m = gpflow.models.VGP([X_augmented, Y_augmented], kernel=kern, likelihood=lik, num_latent_gps=1)
```

After optimization and training, when print the model summary: print_summary(m)
All learnt parameters are shown except of the ones from the likelihood, I had expected to see a vector of variances and means.
Model predict also throws an error:

```
xtest = np.linspace(0, 1, 100)[:, None]
line, = plt.plot(X1, Y1, 'x', mew=2)
mu, var = m.predict_f(np.hstack((xtest, np.zeros_like(xtest))))
```

And the error: tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: cannot compute Mul as input #1(zero-based) was expected to be a double tensor but is a float tensor [Op:Mul]

I believe the model has learnt heteroscedastic noise, but I am just unable to access it. I've also tried to access the parameters through m.trainable_parameters. But as before, no likelihood parameters are shown.

Can someone provide a hint where to look?
(GPflow version 2.9.0)

Edit: The reason for using gpflow.likelihoods.HeteroskedasticTFPConditional()
is that the goal is that each task learns its own noise model.

Comment: Short update: 
Noise parameters are shown, print_summary(m) shows the mean and the variance of the likelihood. In my case by: VGP.q_mu, and VGP.q_sqrt.